# static content page not working in springboot application deployed in Kubernetes cluster

Tags: java, spring-boot, kubernetes

My spring boot application have a simple static html file which I kept in src/main/resources/static/index.html and I have added an extra controller to return this view.

```
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping(path = "${url_prefix}/")
    private String home() {
        return "index.html";
    }

}
```

On my local machine deploy http://localhost:8080/ navigating to the index.html.

Then the same application is deployed into the kubernettes cluster where 
if navigate to the page then it returns

> Whitelabel Error Page
>
> ```
> This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
>
> Thu Jul 11 15:32:14 GMT 2019
> There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
> No message available
> ```

I checked the content of the deployed spring boot jar and I can see the index.html in that jar.

```
  9213 Thu Jul 11 17:10:08 CEST 2019 BOOT-INF/classes/static/index.html
```

I do not have much info about the kubernettes cluster configuration. I am vey well understood that without much info about the deployment scenario, no one can really help me.

But can some one please shed some lights from  higher level point of view ( I know the meaning of 404 error).

Comment: 404 means client side error , means you are accessing something that doesnt exist. I would say you maybe accessing the wrong context path , try it wothout / on the VM or try it on kubernetes the same way as / on the VM

Comment: I am sure this is related to the context path , you maybe accessing it on kubernetes in a diffrent path while u are serving it on the VM as /

Comment: Please edit the question to add all the deployment manifests, `kubectl logs` of pod and any ingress, and also example of URLs you are accessing. We need more information to troubleshoot. I agree it sounds like some path rewriting issue. Maybe you are using an Ingress and need to rewrite the path.

Comment: @AndyShinn I don't have the details of all the deployment manifests because I do not have access to that. I will try the things you guys said and will let you know. Thanks